# Create multiple tags and add different text to them with variable

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to create 4 `<span>` tags and add different text to them.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    var spanElement = document.createElement("span") + i;
    var value_of_span += uniques + i;
    var textnode_of_span = document.createTextNode(value_of_span);
    spanElement.appendChild(textnode_of_span);
    document.getElementById("pristatomiesi_akordai").appendChild(spanElement);
};
```

Comment: you can use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get all values,

Comment: What is the `+i` in `document.createElement("span")+i;` supposed to be? Remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the `+i` in `document.createElement("span")+i;` supposed to be? You are trying to add / concatenate a *DOM element* with a *number*. That doesn't make sense.

Remove it, as well as the `+` in `var value_of_span += uniques+i`. You cannot declare a variable and append to it.

```js
var uniques = 'foo';

for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
  var spanElement = document.createElement("span");
  var value_of_span = uniques + i;
  var textnode_of_span = document.createTextNode(value_of_span);

  spanElement.appendChild(textnode_of_span);
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(spanElement);
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```